# Animating a graph with networkx and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

So I created a simple graph consisting of only 2 nodes:

```
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node(1)
g.add_node(2)
g.add_edge(1, 2)

nx.draw(g, with_labels=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now what I want to do is to create a little animation changing the colors of each node as if I'm traversing the graph, how do I go about this?

Comment: Does this helps: [Animated visualisation of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958425/animated-visualisation-of-an-algorithm)?

Comment: I have an older answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50377764/2912349) that demonstrates how to change networkx node colors in an animation.

Comment: @PaulBrodersen awesome, thanks!